# Anti-captcha com Python, como colocar o token no textarea que não tem botão enviar?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um script com Python, Selenium WebDriver e estou tentando passar um captcha com [anti-captcha](https://anti-captcha.com/) , ele resolve o captcha e me retorna o token, porém estou tendo problema no momento de passar o token para o textarea, ou ao menos isso creio porque a página me dá erro de captcha e esse textarea não tem o botão de enviar. Tentei testar pelo modo desenvolvedor do navegador o textarea, que pelos tutoriais que encontrei, deveria ter esse botão, mas não tem, de qualquer modo, tentei passar pelo console com JavaScrpit:

```
document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML="Palavra de teste"
```

e está indo para este lugar:

```
<input type="hidden" name="gRecaptchaResponse" value="" id="g-recaptcha-response">Palavra de teste</input>
```

Então eu atualizo a página para ver que campo é alterado quando eu clico no quadrado de: Não sou um robot e ele manda o token para um lugar diferente:

```
<input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-token">
```

Detalhe que há dois inputs com este mesmo id, este que recebe é o segundo. Tentei passar texto para simular o token e posteriormente usar no código, então fiz no console:

```
document.getElementById("recaptcha-token").value="palavra de teste"
```

e me retorna:

```
VM25370:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
at <anonymous>:1:49
```

Enfim, o que preciso é passar o token para a propriedade correta e a documentação oficial não explica devidamente esta parte.
Este é o código:

```
def buscar_dados(url, nie, numero, ano):        
    driver, wait = iniciar_driver()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    sleep(2)
    campo_nie = driver.find_element(By.ID,'codigoNieCompleto')
    campo_nie.send_keys(nie)
    sleep(2)
    campo_numero = driver.find_element(By.ID,'numero')
    campo_numero.send_keys(numero)
    sleep(2)
    campo_ano = driver.find_element(By.ID,'yearSolicitud')
    campo_ano.send_keys(ano)
    sleep(5)        
    site_key = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="captchaTramite"]/div/div/div').get_attribute('outerHTML')
    sitekey_clean = site_key.split('" data-expired-callback')[0].split('data-sitekey="')[1]
    print(sitekey_clean)
    solver = recaptchaV2Proxyless()
    solver.set_verbose(1)
    solver.set_key(solver_key)
    solver.set_website_url(url)
    solver.set_website_key(sitekey_clean) 
    g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
    
    if g_response!= 0:
        print(f'g_response:{g_response}')
        driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML="{g_response}"')
        
    else:
        print(f'Task finished with error: {solver.err_string}')              

    sleep(5)
    botao_enviar = driver.find_element(By.ID,'submitNac')
    botao_enviar.click()
```

Answer (score -2):

Saudações
Consegui resolver passando o token com o value:

```
if g_response!= 0:
        print(f'g_response:{g_response}')
        driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value="{g_response}"')
        sleep(15)
        # driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );')
        # driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-demo-submit"]').click()
    else:
        print(f'Task finished with error: {solver.err_string}')
```

Este sleep de 15 segundos é importante para o funcionamento.